# Replace %%20 in string using windows batch script

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, batch-processing

I have a use case where I want to replace %%20 which is part of a string for example: "Calculation%%20One". I want to replace this with "Calculation One".

This where I am stuck:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

>"temp" (
    echo !Option1!
    echo !Option2!
    echo !Option3!
)

set "pattern=%%20"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("temp") do (
    echo data: %%a

    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if "!line:%pattern%=!"=="!line!" (
         set string=!Option1!
         set string2=%!string1!:%%20= %
    ) else (
       set string2=%%a
    )
    endlocal
)

del /q tempFile
```

Can someone please help me with this? I have a program which is a combination of batch and python.

Thanks

Comment: In a batch file, the standard is to double percents as escape characters so try changing your script to read, `%%%%20` and try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear for me why the options are written into a temporary file for processing the values of the environment variables `Option1`, `Option2` and `Option3`. And it would have been good to see the lines which define the environment variables `Option1`, `Option2` and `Option3` for the real values assigned to them.

So I suggest here a batch file which replaces `%20` as found for example in HTML files or emails by a space character in all `Option` environment variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Option1=Calculation%%20One"
set "Option2=Calculation %%%%20Two!"
set "Option3=Any other string"

cls
echo The options before processing:
echo/
set Option

for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set Option 2^>nul') do call :ProcessOption "%%I"

echo/
echo The options after processing:
echo/
set Option
echo/
endlocal
pause
goto :EOF

:ProcessOption
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ModifiedOption=!%~1:%%20= !"
endlocal & set "%~1=%ModifiedOption%"
goto :EOF
```

It is necessary to use delayed expansion on replacing all occurrences of `%20` by a space character because otherwise Windows command interpreter would not know where the environment variable reference with string substitution ends. Replacing a string with percent sign is not possible using immediate expansion for that reason.

The command `set Option` outputs alphabetically sorted all environment variables starting case-insensitive with the string `Option` in format `variable=value` as it can be seen twice on running this batch file.

**FOR** executes this command with using a separate command process started in background and captures all lines written by command **SET** to handle **STDOUT**.

The string `2^>nul` is executed finally as `2>nul` and redirects the error message output by command **SET** to handle **STDERR** to the device **NUL** to suppress it. **SET** would output an error message in case of no environment variable starting with `Option` is defined in current environment. This error condition does not occur with this batch file. Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be interpreted first as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes the entire **FOR** command line before executing the command **FOR** which executes `cmd.exe /c set Option 2>nul` in background.

**FOR** processes the captured output of `set Option` line by line and splits each line up into substrings (tokens) with using the equal sign as delimiter as specified with `delims==`. The string left to first equal sign on each line is assigned to loop variable `I`. This is the name of the environment variable, i.e. `Option1`, `Option2` and `Option3` for this batch file.

With each `OptionX` environment variable name the subroutine `ProcessOption` is called for replacing all `%20` in its value by a space character.

Here is a solution for environment variables with one or more exclamation marks in variable name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "!Option1!=Calculation%%%%20One"
set "!Option2!=City%%20Country"
set "!Option3!=State%%%%20Country"
set "!Option4!=Any other address/string"

cls
echo The options before processing:
echo/
set !Option

for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set !Option 2^>nul') do call :ProcessOption "%%I"

echo/
echo The options after processing:
echo/
set !Option
echo/
endlocal
pause
goto :EOF

:ProcessOption
call set "ModifiedOption=%%%~1%%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ModifiedOption=!ModifiedOption:%%%%20= !"
set "ModifiedOption=!ModifiedOption:%%20= !"
endlocal & set "ModifiedOption=%ModifiedOption%"
set "%~1=%ModifiedOption%"
set "ModifiedOption="
goto :EOF
```

This batch code replaces `%20` AND `%%20` in all environment variables starting with `!Option` in name by a space character in comparison to above replacing just `%20` by a space in environment variables beginning with `Option` in name.

It is of course a bad idea to use characters in variable names which have a special meaning for Windows command interpreter like the characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~|<>% ``. It is possible as demonstrated above, but it is definitely not a good idea.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of `&` operator.

And read DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) why it is better to use `echo/` instead of `echo`. to output an empty line.