# Use an expanded variable in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I would like to know if there is a way where I can use a for loop on an expanded variable.

Is it something recommended or which can be done?

I have a script which reads a text file which has many dimensions such as `State%%20Country`, `City%%20Country`, etc. I save them into a variable (lets call it `!P!`). So `!P1!` now has:

```
!P1!
City%%20Country
State%%20Country
...
```

The script runs a for loop and reads each row and based on that the value of `!P1!` changes.

I would like to know or appreciate if some one can let me know I can loop over the variable as I would like to replace the `%%20` which is part of the string contained in `!P1!` with <kbd>Space</kbd>.

So what I am trying is :

```
for /F "delims==" %%A in ('!P1!') do ...
```

I know this wont work, but can someone let me know if there is a way to do this or if this is the right approach?

Comment: Is a batch file really the best way to process this sort of data?

Comment: Don't put single quotes around text files in `for` loop sets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String replacement in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772456/string-replacement-in-batch-file)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "p1=something%%%%20or%%%%20other"
SET "repl=%%%%20"
SET "p1=!p1:%repl%= !"
FOR %%a IN (%p1%) DO ECHO %%a
```

Not sure whether your problem has to do with a variable named `!p1!` or you are using delayed expansion on variable `p1`. The above may assist.

Comment: You think the environment variables have the name `P1`, `P2`, ... but you are wrong. Anks named the environment variables `!P1!`, `!P2!`, ... Yes, really, the environment variable names contain at begin and end an exclamation mark. You might not believe that, but it's true. This question by Anks is a duplicate of [Replace %%20 in string using windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416238/) where the working code is already posted (and accepted). The problem here is that Anks has no idea what he/she is doing.

Comment: @Mofi : Even though I've been unemployed now effectively for 16 years, I still can't find the time to research prior answers - never mind remember them. I suppose I just assume that since the automatic reaction these days is to google it, and that would be my first port of call if I had a problem, then OP would have done so. I really don't have the time or inclination to do the basic research that should have been done before posting a question. Congratulations on your power of recall.

Comment: @Mofi I have the answer from the previous question, want to try/learn this approach.